# docker export / import error: archive/tar: invalid tar header (from ubuntu18.04 to jetson nano)

Tags: docker, ubuntu, import, export, ros

I'm trying to export a docker form ubuntu18.04, and import it into jetson nano.
ubuntu18.04: "docker export -o xxx.tar "
jetson_nano: "docker import xxx.tar"
then I got the error: "Error response from daemon: Error processing tar file(exit status 1): archive/tar: invalid tar header"

first, I use "docker export > xxx.tar", and I find some suggestions using "docker export -o xxx.tar “
but it is still not work.

why I want to transport a docker from ubuntu to jetson nano( also a linux os), I complie a ros project succeed in ubuntu18.04's docker, and failed in jetson nano's docker. All steps are the same. this really confused me.

add:
ubuntu18.04 docker version : 19.03.8
jeston nano docker version : 18.08.7

can any body help me? thanks.

Comment: You almost never need `docker export` or `import`; you should be able to `docker run` a new container based on the same image on the other system.  Can you describe in a little more detail what you're trying to do with these commands?  Have you checked that the files are identical on both systems, and that it's not unexpectedly compressed or anything like that?

Comment: In my conputer which os is ubuntu, I pull the ros:melodic-ros-base image, and execute docker run, now I get a ros docker, in this docker, I compile ccm-slam project successfully. Otherwise, In my jetson nano, I do the same work, pull a ros iamge, docker run the image, complie the ccm-slam project ,but this time, I failed. So I want to copy my computer's docker which is compile correctly to jetson nano, so that I need not to handle the complie error. But this "copy" idea got the " invalid tar header" error.

Comment: as your suggestion, I check the md5, using "md5sum -b xxx.tar" in ubuntu and jetson nano, I find the MD5 code is different. I transfer xxx.tar by U disk, And I have no idea why they are different.